# Number of ways to sample $x$ beads from 3 red beads, 3 green beads, and 3 blue beads

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I wanted to sample $x$ beads from 3 green, 3 blue, and 3 red beads (apart from colour, the beads are not distinct). I've been trying to find one equation I can use to solve for something like this (likely involving combinatorics), but I can't seem to figure it out. For $x=1$ the answer is just $3\choose1$. For $x=2$, if the beads are of different colours there are 3 ways, and if the beads are of the same colour there is also 3 choices to choose, so I get a total of 6. But I can't seem to find a pattern here to come up with one unified equation.

Comment: Coefficient of $z^x$ in expansion of $(1+z+z^2+z^3)^3 = \left(\frac{1-z^4}{1-z}\right)^3$

Comment: Are you sampling with or without replacement?  Are you treating order as relevant?

Comment: Sampling without replacement, order is irrelevant.

Comment: @BeepBoop did my answer help you ? if so , can you acept it ?

Answer (score 1):

we will use generating functions Then , if the same color of beads are different from each other :

Generating function for different red beads = $$1 + C(3,1)x + C(3,2)x^2 + C(3,3)x^3 = 1+3x +3x^2 +x^3$$

Generating function for different blue beads = $$1 + C(3,1)x + C(3,2)x^2 + C(3,3)x^3 = 1+3x +3x^2 +x^3$$

Generating function for different green beads = $$1 + C(3,1)x + C(3,2)x^2 + C(3,3)x^3 = 1+3x +3x^2 +x^3$$

Then find the coefficient of $[x^k]$ in the expansion of $$(  1+3x +3x^2 +x^3)^3$$

If the same color beads are not distinct then :

Generating function for  red beads = $$ 1+x +x^2 +x^3$$

Generating function for  blue beads = $$ 1+x +x^2 +x^3$$

Generating function for  green beads = $$  1+x +x^2 +x^3$$

Then find the coefficient of $[x^k]$ in the expansion of $$(  1+x +x^2 +x^3)^3$$